# Unable to log in to heroku through CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

My password for heroku works in the browser but not in the CLI. I've changed my heroku password twice and the same outcome occur after every change: I can log in through my browser, but not through my CLI (using windows powershell if that matters). Here is the error I get in the CL:

```
PS C:\Users\rjfor\OneDrive\Documents\beyond basics\python projects\webpages\mysite> heroku login
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email [4workanswers@gmail.com]: y
Password: *********
 »   Error: Invalid credentials provided.
 »
 »   Error ID: unauthorized
PS C:\Users\rjfor\OneDrive\Documents\beyond basics\python projects\webpages\mysite> heroku login
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email [4workanswers@gmail.com]: y
Password: *********
 »   Error: Invalid credentials provided.
 »
 »   Error ID: unauthorized
```

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: just check the version type in terminal or cmd  `heroku --version`

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Irrespective of what you get on screen please enter the listed below commands.

1. `heroku --version`
2. `heroku login`
3. When it ask for the email-d please write `4workanswers@gmail.com` (your email id) not `y` even if it's showing your email on screen
4. Now enter your password(make sure you type it correctly)

> One advice while entering your password. First type your password in a **Notepad/gedit/TextEdit** than switch browser and open [heroku login](https://id.heroku.com/login) and than paste the password from the **Notepad/gedit/TextEdit**. Do it same in **terminal/cmd** when it ask for password **don't write** just paste using `mouse right click(Primary)`.
>
> Just to try!!!Update heroku to the latest version

Comment: Thank you!!!! I just got it to work. That's a really good idea you have highlighted! Many thanks!!

Comment: **accept** this answer and **up-vote** it to show the community you are satisfied with the answer and you don't need further answer....it will saves time of other geeks @RobertForwerck

Comment: when i do this in the current version `heroku/7.59.4 win32-x64 node-v12.21.0` I get a browser pop up to log me in, then had me close it and go back to powershell.  Then it gives me this error: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:/Users/userName/_netrc'`

Answer (score 0):

You are typing in `y` as your email. If you just want to reuse the previous email you just press `enter` or type in the full email again.